# start vi automatically in hex mode

Tags: startup, key-bindings, xxd

Once I run `vi a.out`, I can type `:%!xxd`, but I'm unable to automate the process like

- start vi automatically in hex mode
- create a key mapping from <kbd>F1</kbd> to `:%!xxd`

Answer (score 6):

To start vim automatically in hex mode when editing a.out, put an autocommand like this one in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
au BufReadPost a.out silent %!xxd
```

A more complete explanation with examples can be found at:

```
:help using-xxd
```

To use key mapping instead, mapping , for example, use this:

```
map <F3> :%!xxd<CR>
```

Comment: The last "map" suggestion is ineffective. I put that line into my .vimrc file. When I launch vi on a.out, the other configurations in .vimrc are working, but when I hit F3, i hear a beep and the cursor moves down a line. No xxd happening

Comment: My guess is that your Vim does not know the escape sequence for `<F3>`. Try this: run Vim and start insert mode, e.g. by typing `a`. Then type `Ctrl-K`, not those letters but hold the `Ctrl` key and type the letter `k`. Then hit your `F3` key. You should see the four characters `<F3>`. You will probably see something else. If so, the reason could be that your `$TERM` variable does not match the terminal you are actually using, or the code for your `F3` key is missing from your terminal's terminfo database entry. One solution would be to create another mapping to define `<F3>`, e.g.,

Comment: `map <Esc>[13~ <F3>`.

Comment: Something else you can do to see what terminal keys Vim knows about, usually from the termcap/terminfo database, is to execute `:set termcap`.